lapack.lib does not install with CodeBlocks
I have installed codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe. I have picked a GNU FORTRAN compiler, but I cannot find the libraries lapack and blas. I tried to reinstall Codeblocks but it didn't work. Does windows 11 affect the installation of libraries in Codeblocks ? I have reinstalled codeclocks last year in windows 10 but didn't have a similar problem. The libraries were already installed in codeblocks.
I tried to reinstall codeblocks but it didn't work.

"Code::Blocks is a free C/C++ and Fortran IDE", that is, CodeBlocks provides the functionality for editing and calling a outside compiler. It doesn't have the responsibility to provide those libraries. You should download them yourself, and, you should use a new compiler Instead of the one inside CodeBlocks Installation. Lapack Library

Hello, these libraries though are for Linux, does it have also Windows?

Hi, can you configure to use MSYS2 toolchain? It provides a Windows package of lapack. You can follow the instructions on MSYS2 official site to Install a suitable toolchain for FORTRAN. Also, you can specify a compiler in CodeBlocks->Settings->Compiler->Toolchain executable.
